# how can i print return value in stored prosedure?

Tags: sql-server

```
ALTER Procedure     [dbo].[sp1] 
@ID int
As
IF(SELECT Grade FROM Tb1 WHERE ID=@ID)BETWEEN 15 AND 20
RETURN   'A'
else
RETURN  'B'



Declare @ID1 int 
EXEC   @ID1= sp1 '3';
Print convert(varchar(10) , @ID)
Go
```

Comment: with id 3 grade is 19

Comment: i want prosedure print A

Answer (score 0):

Seems you got confused in writing that query, I hope the following query helps you

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp1] 
@ID int 
As 
BEGIN
SELECT CASE WHEN MARKS BETWEEN 15 AND 20 THEN
'A'
ELSE
'B'
END AS 'GRADE' 
FROM [TABLE] WHERE ID=@ID
END
```

Comment: I want save prosedure and use that

Comment: how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get output value of stored proc,if you want to consume entire output ,below is the way.

below is the way to consume entire sp output:

```
declare @test table
(id int)


create proc usp_test123
as
begin
select 1
end

insert into @test
exec usp_test123

select * from @test
```

Else you can use output to return and conusme specific values

```
create proc usp_test1234
(
@id int out
)
as
begin
select @id=1
end

declare @id int
exec usp_test1234
@id =@id output
select @id
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do, but here's a way to fetch A/B grade with an output parameter in the procedure and then print it:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[sp1] 
@ID int,
@Grade char(1) output
As
IF (exists (SELECT 1  FROM Tb1 WHERE ID=@ID and Grade BETWEEN 15 AND 20))
set @Grade = 'A'
else 
set @Grade = 'B'
go


Declare @ID1 int, @Grade char(1)
set @ID1 = 3 
EXEC   sp1 @ID1, @Grade output
Print @Grade
```